# REACT-REDUX-EXPRESS, unable to update user fields, 404 ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

I am trying to update user information (name, email, password) but getting two errors.

1. If I try to enter & update name or Email (DATA DOES NOT GET UPDATED) I get 404 error :
   [image]

Request:
[image]

Response:
[image]

2. But, if I try to enter and update Password it gets UPDATED (as I have to enter new password while logging in again) but it shows these error's immediately after submit button:
   [image]

I have tried updating user data by putting data directly through *thunder client* & it's getting updated:
[image]

Here is my source code:

### **FRONTEND**

**ProfileScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import ErrorMessage from "../../components/ErrorMessage/ErrorMessage";
import Message from "../../components/Message/Message";
import Loader from "../../components/Loader/Loader";
import {
  getUserDetails,
  updateUserProfile,
} from "../../redux/actions/userActions";
import "./ProfileScreen.scss";
import { USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET } from "../../redux/constants/userConstants";

const ProfileScreen = ({ location, history }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  const regex =
    /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { loading, error, user } = userDetails;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const userUpdateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateProfile);
  const { success } = userUpdateProfile;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history.push("/login");
    } else {
      if (!user.name || !user || success) {
        dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET });
        dispatch(getUserDetails("profile"));
      } else {
        setName(user.name);
        setEmail(user.email);
      }
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, dispatch, user, success]);

  const passwordHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    !regex.test(password)
      ? setMessage(
          "Password must contain atleast 8 characters & one alphabet, number & special character"
        )
      : password !== confirmPassword
      ? setMessage("Passwords do not match!")
      : dispatch(updateUserProfile({ id: user._id, password }));
  };

  const enameHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(updateUserProfile({ id: user._id, name, email, password }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="profile-container">
        <div className="profile">
          {message && <ErrorMessage error={message} />}
          {error && <ErrorMessage error={error} />}
          {success && <Message success={"Profile Updated"} />}
          <div className="profile-form">
            <h2>User Profile</h2>
            {loading ? (
              <Loader />
            ) : (
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={enameHandler}>
                  <div className="profile-form-items">
                    <h3> Update Name or Email</h3>
                    <input
                      className="profile-input"
                      type="name"
                      placeholder="New Name"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                      className="profile-input"
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="New Email address"
                      value={email}
                      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <button type="submit" value="submit">
                      Update
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <form onSubmit={passwordHandler}>
                  <div className="profile-form-items">
                    <h3>Update Password</h3>
                    <input
                      className="profile-input"
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="New Password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <input
                      className="profile-input"
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Confirm New Password"
                      value={confirmPassword}
                      onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" value="submit">
                      Update
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProfileScreen;
```

**userAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
  USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGOUT,
  USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
  USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login",
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
  localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOGOUT,
  });
};

export const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users",
      { name, email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const getUserDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const updateUserProfile = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    console.log("UPDATE Action called");

    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile`, user, config);

    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**userReducer.js**

```
import {
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST,
  USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

export const userUpdateProfileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

// reducers
 import {
  userLoginReducer,
  userRegisterReducer,
  userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfileReducer,
} from "./reducers/userReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
});

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

### **BACKEND**

**userRoutes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  authUser,
  getUserProfile,
  registerUser,
  updateUserProfile,
} = require("../controllers/userController");
const protect = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser);
router.post("/login", authUser);
router
  .route("/profile")
  .get(protect, getUserProfile)
  .put(protect, updateUserProfile);

module.exports = router;
```

**userController.js**

```
//  @description: Update user profile
//  @route:       PUT /api/users/profile
//  @access:      Private
exports.updateUserProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
      user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;

      if (req.body.password) {
        user.password = req.body.password;
      }

      const updatedUser = await user.save();

      res.json({
        _id: updatedUser._id,
        name: updatedUser.name,
        email: updatedUser.email,
        isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(updatedUser._id),
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("User not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**authMiddleware.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const protect = async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      error = new Error("Not Authorized!!");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    const error = new Error("Not Authorized!!, No Token!!");
    error.status = 401;
    next(error);
  }
};

module.exports = protect;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is (most probably) in

```
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
```

check if you are getting the "req.user._id" correctly. And also check your authMiddlwere if there is any error in getting req.user._id .

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I am getting correct User ID in return. In-fact I have checked my back-end through [thunder client](https://www.thunderclient.io/) and everything is working fine (I am able to update name, email and password).  What I think is, that the main problem is in react-redux code.

Comment: No, I mean the error is being generated by this line. And this line is related to getting the req.user._id correctly. If your backend is working fine, then check if the token being sent  correctly in the  ==  Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`, ==, ie, try console log the userInfo.token

Comment: OK, so I did & got `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwYzZkZjIyZjI1ZDM4MWU3OGFiNWYzMiIsImlhdCI6MTYyMzk5MzI0NSwiZXhwIjoxNjI2NTg1MjQ1fQ.5nnCj1GCqR_anD7UQKaJTbxZUDDBaVEfE4JcHaw_z_g` after console log `userInfo.token` & token stored in my local storage is `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYwYzZkZjIyZjI1ZDM4MWU3OGFiNWYzMiIsImlhdCI6MTYyMzk5MzI0NSwiZXhwIjoxNjI2NTg1MjQ1fQ.5nnCj1GCqR_anD7UQKaJTbxZUDDBaVEfE4JcHaw_z_g` I compared the text here [Text Compare!](https://text-compare.com/) and its same. I tried clearing storage and logged in again but the result is same.

Comment: can you share your authMiddleware?